# MEF DirectoryCatalog not loading single Export, all others work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mef

So I have a single dll that MEF will not load from. It just ignores the DLL entirely and doesn't load it.

A manual `Assembly.Load("assemblyname")` works fine without errors.

I cannot find any output trace statements or anything.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this single DLL would not load and all others that are referenced exactly the same way with the same export attribute work fine? (Also same version of .net, same everything)

Anyone know how I can actually get a log of failures on load and why?

Thanks!

Comment: By manual, do you mean AssemblyCatalog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was a typo in a csproj file. Thanks though!